# Audio mute is not working

Tags: ios, audio, mute, linphone-sdk

i'm trying to implement a mute button in a sample application.

i've seen linphone is doing this by changing the BOOL value for the following code.

**linphone_core_enable_mic(LC,TRUE);**

i also did the same, but i'm getting this warning 
ortp-warning-Could not apply gain on sent RTP packets: gain control wasn't activated. Use  audio_stream_enable_gain_control() before starting the stream.

how to solve this ?

Comment: Did u use AVAudioPlayerDelegate. in your project ?

Comment: Are you familiar with linphone SDK ?

Comment: No , i m sorry because i would never use this SDK

Comment: That's alright @HimanshuMoradiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed to include the submodules in the project from Linphone project, thus solved the problem.

Comment: Let me know if anybody need more details.

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue in my project when I try to make an outgoing call via Linphone SDK. 

`mediastreamer-warning-Could not apply gain on sent RTP packets: gain control wasn't activated. Use audio_stream_enable_gain_control() before starting the stream.`

`ortp-warning-Fail to set IPv4 packet info on RTP socket: Invalid argument.`

I've included Linphone project via cocoapods (pod 'linphone-sdk', '~> 5.2.50') so I don't think submodules are missed. However just in case I would accept any help I can get :)